# What is the name of this Rummy variant?

Tags: identify-this-game, rummy

It's called Devil's Delight by the people I know but I can't find any google results for it. Does any one know what people call this?

The game is played with two decks and everyone gets seven cards passed to them. Then the deck is put into the middle of the table with the first card placed up. The person after the dealer takes the first turn.

**EDIT**: At the start of a turn, a player is passed a card from the previous player. They can either take the card, or pass it to the next person who must pick it up along with another card. Then you must discard a card, and the next person can either pick it up or pass.

The goal of the game is to make sets and runs depending on the round. First round is three sets, next round is one run with two sets, the round after that is two runs etc. Twos are wild and can be played anywhere. After you get your required sets and runs you can put them on the table (*go down*). Once you do you can play on other players who are down and take their 2s that are down. Also, sets are three cards and runs are four cards of the same suit. One hand has a seven card run in it.

The round ends when someone has no cards in their hand. Then players add up their cards which turn into points. number cards (3 through 9) is 5 points, 10 and any face card is 10 points, an A is 15 points and a 2 is 30 points. The player with the lowest score at the end of seven rounds wins.

Comment: What actually happens on a players turn?  Does a 'set' have a minimum number or cards (if you only have 7 or do you acquire more).   What you're describing sounds like a variant of Rummy based on having a deck with one card face up and players collecting sets/runs.

Answer (score 3):

It's just one of many forms of a class of games called Contract Rummy. (The various rounds' goals are called contracts).

The major variation here seems to be:

The discard (or rather lack of discard): I guess by your description (since one cannot make three sets with only seven cards) that players just draw a card each turn and are not required (or permitted) to discard, but rather can only play melds and lay off on other melds.

See more common versions at, for example, http://www.rummy-games.com/rules/contract-rummy.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like [frustration](https://adventuresallaround.com/frustration-card-game-rules-camping/)

Frustration involves 'going down' when you can meet the required hand for the round and the round ending as soon as the first person is out of cards.  If you are not 'down' when the first person gets rid of all their cards then you have to repeat the round while the rest move on to the next round